# How do I filter out resources on a daily basis in fullCalendar (filterResourcesWithEvents)

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to filter out resources **on a daily basis** in a fullcalendar that implements a resourceTimeGrid for all days where a given resource does not have any events.

For example, in the picture below, Susan should not be displayed on Thursday, as she doesn't have any events.

The setting [filterResourcesWithEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/filterResourcesWithEvents) only seems to have an effect when no events for Susan are present for the entire week.

[image]

Comment: This isn't possible, sorry. You can ask for feature requests - there are details on the fullCalendar website about how you can do that. IMHO though what you're asking for has the potential to create quite a confusing and inconsistent user experience, I'm not sure it would work well in reality.

Comment: Indeed this does not seem possible. A feature request that goes in that sense already seems to exist and is accepted: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4290